# Not able to cache the main_frame requests

Tags: caching, http-headers, cache-control

I am working on a chrome extension which modifies the http response headers.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-cache/fglobbnbihckpkodmeefhagijjcjnbeh/details

I am not able to cache main_frame requests. I am able to control the caching of the static requests though.

For example if I hit http://apple.com I receive the following headers for the main_frame.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=276
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:3310
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 12 Mar 2013 09:24:12 GMT
Expires:Tue, 12 Mar 2013 09:28:48 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

But every time I hit the url the browser tries to access the server and ultimately receive a 200 response. I have tried all the possible combinations that the headers can be set to enable caching on the main_frame.

I want that when the user hits the url from the navigation bar of chrome and no requests are made.

Comment: @RobW its not about the code really, I just want to know the right headers which will make the browser cache the file.

Comment: You've added the google-chrome-extension tag, and some header-related tags. So, you probably have some code using the `chrome.webRequest` API. Including the code would greatly help others to evaluate whether your problem matches their problem (and Googling would also be easier).

Comment: Its better that I update the tags. I don't want to confuse people by making them think its an extension related problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some sort of cache validation in your response headers. `ETag` header can be used to control that, by adding values to it that would identify a unique response. You can read a bit about it in the [Apache ETag documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag), but I'd simply include `ETag: [filename]` in your response headers in your example:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=276
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:3310
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 12 Mar 2013 09:24:12 GMT
Expires:Tue, 12 Mar 2013 09:28:48 GMT
Server:Apache
ETag: File:"somefile.html"
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

These `ETag` values can include pretty much anything, such as file name, file size, custom values,... that can be separated by a semicolon `;`. If the values include spaces, then enclose them in double quotation marks `"`. For Example:

```
ETag: File:"YouTube_cd_Fdly3rX8.jpg"; Size:12169
```

Together with `Cache-Control`, `Expires` and some other header values that might change (when included and browser knows how to interpret them), will form a basis for Browser's cache validator.

Looking at your sample response headers, you might want to increase the *max-age* value in your `Cache-Control` to a lot higher value, as your example suggest they should be cached client-side for only 276 seconds. The `Expires` header value also seems a bit short.

More on how to set these values and how browsers are expected to validate cache control headers can be read in the [RFC2616, Section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9).

**EDIT:** After further debugging, checking and re-checking the behavior of Chrome's cache validation, it turns out it indeed doesn't respect properly set `Cache-Control` response headers. On request of the OP, I've reported this issue to the Chrome support:

> **Chrome, Version 25.0.1364.172 m**
>
> Disrespecting Cache-Control on main document requests when serving
>   static files from a web server, while respecting same header response
>   on linked contents.
>
> **Test setup:**
>
> Requesting a static HTML document from a web server (MIME text/html),
>   that contains another static HTML document withing an IFRAME (also
>   MIME text/html). The IFRAME served document has same response headers
>   attached to it by a web server response as the main document:
>
> ```
> Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 16:29:28 GMT
> Expires: Thu, 21 Mar 2013 16:33:59 GMT
> Cache-Control: max-age=301, max-stale=299, only-if-cached
> ```
>
> **Expected behavior:**
>
> Main document and the document served within an IFRAME will be cached
>   locally with initial request for the duration of at least 301
>   (max-age) seconds, and additional 299 (max-stale) seconds for normal
>   (non-forced) load requests. Any subsequent requests within this
>   time-frame of 301 seconds that aren't expected to invalidate local
>   cache (such as forced-refresh with CTRL+F5 or Reload context menu
>   command) and are initiated by a normal page load request (e.g.
>   re-entering relevant URL in the address bar) will be loaded from the
>   local cache with a status message 200 OK (from cache), if none of the
>   local cache controlling information indicates it otherwise (same URL,
>   requested within valid cache time-frame, document was tagged to be
>   cached in its response headers correctly).
>
> **Problem:**
>
> The main document is not loaded via its cached copy and an additional
>   request is made to the web server, resulting in a status code 304 Not
>   Modified. The document within an IFRAME however is loaded from the
>   local cache correctly and results in a status message 200 OK (from
>   cache).
>
> **Notes:**
>
> None of the cache-control tags or any combination of their values seem
>   to have any positive effect on the behavior of local cache for the
>   main document. Including a non-unique ETag value does not resolve the
>   problem of caching main document either. Other major vendor browsers
>   (tested in IE, Firefox, Opera) respect Cache-Control headers on main
>   document.

Comment: setting these headers work fine with static resources but when all "document" type requests are always verified by the server thus resulting in a 304 response. I expect the document type requests also to be fetched from cache directly. I am using chrome as my browser.

Comment: @TidalWave, right now I am setting a max-age value as well as expires header. All these settings work pretty well for Static resources. They  dont work with the document type resource. I feel that chrome does not cache document type requests at all. Do you know some site where the document type resource is cached such that the browser does not even make requests at all to the server?

Comment: @TidalWave, please move this conversation to chat. I am really desperate to see the link. I dont have rights to create a chat I think.

Comment: Could u put the link of the chrome bug that u have reported please?

Comment: @TildalWave You can see all of your reported issues by [searching for "Open and reported by me"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=4&q=&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Iteration+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles).